# Balancing out MYSQL select statements

Tags: mysql

I inserted 'vanity_name' and 'name' into the first and second SELECT statements respectively.

I get a mismatched number of columns error, which I'm confused about because I added a column to both select statements to maintain a balance.

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT id, 
       vanity_name, 
       Date_format(DATE, '%M %e, %Y') AS DATE, 
       TYPE 
FROM   (SELECT resume_id AS id, 
               date_mod  AS DATE, 
               'resume'  AS TYPE 
        FROM   resumes 
        WHERE  user_id = '1' 
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT profile_id, 
               name, 
               date_mod AS DATE, 
               'profile' 
        FROM   profiles 
        WHERE  user_id = '1' 
        ORDER  BY DATE DESC 
        LIMIT 
        5) AS d1 
ORDER  BY DATE DESC
```

Comment: Looks like your 'vanity_name' column is missing in the select.

Comment: Formatting your code makes the error pretty obvious. I recommend adopting coding standards.

Comment: When you use UNION make sure number, order, types of columns matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Erm, you have *four* columns in your outer select, *three* in the inner select.

> id, vanity_name, date, type

vs.

> id, date, TYPE

Comment: Thanks! I see this was a silly mistake. I put both values in the subselect and the query is working. The only thing is, I can't access the vanity_name or name variables. Do I need to request them in the main select as resumes.vanity_name?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the parenthesis, you're trying to union:

(SELECT resume_id AS id, date_mod AS date, 'resume' AS TYPE  FROM resumes WHERE user_id = '1'

with

SELECT profile_id,name,date_mod AS date, 'profile'   FROM profiles   ...  LIMIT 5)

and they obviously don't match. Reposition your parens.